# Minimizing cubic over elliptic disk without using derivatives

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Given $x, y$ satisfy $(x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 + 2xy \leq 32$. Find the minimum value of:

$$P = x^3 + y^3 +3(xy-1)(x+y-2)$$

**My attempt:**

From $(x-4)^2 + (y-4)^2 + 2xy \leq 32$, I get:

$$(x+y)^2 - 8(x+y) \leq 0$$
$$\implies 0 \leq x+y \leq 8$$

From $P = x^3 + y^3 +3(xy-1)(x+y-2)$, I get:

$$P = (x+y)^3 - 6xy - 3(x+y) + 6 \geq (x+y)^3 - 3(x+y)^2 - 3(x+y) + 6$$

I can use derivatives to find the minimum value but my teacher told me to try to solve this without derivatives. Is there a way to do that?

*Edit:* There was a mistake in my solving. I was using AM-GM inequality to derive this:

$$- 6xy \geq - \frac{3(x+y)^2}{2}$$

But I forgot that $x$ and $y$ are both real and can be negative.

So now I fixed it. Instead of $\frac{3(x+y)^2}{2}$, it should be $3(x+y)^2$ since $2xy \leq (x + y)^2$

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh yes. That was a mistake.

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh now I've realised something wrong in my solving. I was actually using AM-GM inequality to derive $- 6xy \geq - \frac{3(x+y)^2}{2}$, but forgot that x and y are real, not positive integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can.

Let $x+y=2u$ and $xy=v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative.

Thus, the condition gives $$(x+y)^2-8(x+y)\leq0$$ or
$$0\leq u\leq4.$$
Now, since $u^2\geq v^2$ it's $(x-y)^2\geq0$, we obtain: $$P=8u^3-6uv^2+3(v^2-1)(2u-2)=8u^3-6v^2-6u+6\geq$$
$$\geq8u^3-6u^2-6u+6=\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\frac{3}{2}u+\frac{1}{8}-6u+6=$$
$$=\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\frac{15}{4}\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{17}{4}=$$
$$=\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{125}}{8}-\frac{15}{4}\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{17}{4}-\frac{5\sqrt5}{4}\geq$$
$$\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt{125}}{8}\right)^2}-\frac{15}{4}\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{17}{4}-\frac{5\sqrt5}{4}=\frac{17-5\sqrt5}{4}.$$
We used the following inequality.
$$\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3+\frac{\sqrt{125}}{4}\geq\frac{15}{4}\left(2u-\frac{1}{2}\right),$$ which is
$$\left(u-\frac{1+\sqrt5}{4}\right)^2\left(u+\frac{2\sqrt5-1}{4}\right)\geq0,$$ which is true for $u\geq0.$

The equality occurs for $x=y=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{4},$ which says that we got a mninimal value.

Comment: This solution looks very good. Just a thought, I think we can just let $xy = v$ instead of $xy = v^2$ since mostly we work with $u$ and let $xy = v$ doesn't affect the solution. Having "$v^2$ can be negative" seems not familiar with me since I haven't work with imaginary numbers yet. Anyway, thanks for your work!

Comment: @windows prime You are welcome. We don'd need to think about $v$ in my substitution.  The substitution $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$ named the $uvw$'s substitution. This substitution really helps in the work with symmetric homogeneous polynomials of three variables.